# Implement interface in class or as member

Tags: c#, oop

When is it usefull to implement the interface directly in a class and when
is it better to have a field member of the interface type?

Comment: These two solutions serve for completely different tasks. Read some about SOLID and OOP paradigms. Also you can read GOF.

Comment: I recommend reading about the principle of [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of whether you want your class to be able to **do something**, or **have something**.

case 1 impl:

```
public class Car : ICanPlayRadio
{
    // impl. ICanPlayRadio
    public void TurnOnRadio() { ... }
}
```

case 2 impl:

```
public class Car
{
    public IRadio Radio { get; set;}
}
```

use case 1:

```
Car myCar = new Car();
myCar.TurnOnRadio(); // my car can turn on the radio
```

use case 2:

```
Car myCar = new Car();
myCar.Radio.TurnOn(); // my car has a radio, it can be turned on
```

In this example, case 2 makes more sense to me. It all depends on your model.

**UPDATE:**

*"Whats the benefit in using an interface for the radio?"*

The benefit of using an interface for the Radio property is that the car class can accept IRadio instances (usually passed into constructor). So you can create two cars having two different radio implementations, but when it comes to turning the radio on, you can be sure they both can do it b/c of the interface working as a contract of what can be done.

```
public class FMRadio : IRadio { ... } 
public class AppleCarPlay : IRadio { ... } 

Car volvo740 = new Car(new FMRadio());
Car audiA7 = new Car(new AppleCarPlay());

volvo740.Radio.TurnOn(); // turns on last FM radio frequency 
audiA7.Radio.TurnOn();  // plays my favorite spotify playlist
```

Comment: The second one looks better to me. But wouldn't it be better to have the radio as abstract class? Whats the benefit in using an interface for the radio?

Comment: To be fair, with an abstract class you can accept a type of that base class in your constructor, and you'll also know that your derived types will have the `TurnOn` method because they derive from the abstract base. The thing in both cases is that you're not guaranteed to have a fully implemented method - instead it could throw a `NotImplementedException`. The benefit I've found for using interfaces is that interfaces can be easily mocked and stubbed when unit testing, but honestly I only use interfaces where needed, and abstract base classes elsewhere, all to fit the overall design.